# navbar position fixed upon scroll from the second section onward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have used animate scroll and scrollify plugin in my html for different scrolling effect.but the problem is iwant my navbar from the second section onward (not in the first section).i have tried `window.scrolltop()`and `offset().top` and `position.top` in jquery but its not getting fixed anyway.here is my html with css code
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Welcome!!!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/Lato-Light.ttf"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom_style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" /> -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="content-fluid"    style="min-width: 300px;">
         <div class="row">
            <section class="panel welcome col-lg-12" data-section-name="welcome">
               <header class="col-lg-7 header_overwrite">
                  <div class="col-lg-8 wrapper">
                     <h1 class="h1_style" id="greetings"></h1>
                  </div>
               </header>
               <a href="#home" class="scroll">Scroll down to Browse</a>    
            </section>

            <section class="panel home col-lg-12" data-section-name="home">   
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="fixed_nav hidden ">
                        <div class=" col-lg-2 btn-color-shihab">
                            <a href="#" onclick="$('body').animatescroll();"><span><h1>Shihab.me</h1></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-lg-2 btn-color-home">
                            <a href="#home"><span><h1>Home</h1></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-lg-2 btn-color-resume">
                            <a href="#" onclick="$('#section-2').animatescroll();"><span><h1>Resume</h1></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-lg-2 btn-color-skill">
                            <a href="#" onclick="$('#section-3').animatescroll();"><span><h1>Skill</h1></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-lg-2 btn-color-portfolio">
                            <a href="#"><span><h1>Portfolio</h1></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-lg-2 btn-color-contact">
                            <a href="#"><span><h1>Contact</h1></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="panel resume col-lg-12" data-section-name="resume">
              <div id="section-2">
                <div class="content-wrapper w70">                                
                  <h1>What is it exactly?</h1>
                  <p><strong>AnimateScroll</strong> is a jQuery plugin which enables you to <strong>scroll to any part of the page
                    in style</strong> by just calling the <code>animatescroll()</code> function with the <code>Id</code> or <code>Classname</code>
                    of the element where you want to scroll to.</p>                                
                    <p><strong>Basic usage:</strong></p>
                    <pre><code class="language-javascript">$('body').animatescroll();</code></pre>
                    <button class="btn demo-btn" onclick="$('body').animatescroll();">Click for a Demo</button>
                    <p>
                      It gives power to the user with its various options to customize the style of scrolling, scroll speed and many more.
                      Supports more than 30 unique Scrolling Styles.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
              <section class="panel skill col-lg-12" data-section-name="skill">
                  <div id="section-3">
                    <div class="content-wrapper w70">                                
                      <h1>What is it exactly?</h1>
                      <p><strong>AnimateScroll</strong> is a jQuery plugin which enables you to <strong>scroll to any part of the page
                        in style</strong> by just calling the <code>animatescroll()</code> function with the <code>Id</code> or <code>Classname</code>
                        of the element where you want to scroll to.</p>                                
                        <p><strong>Basic usage:</strong></p>
                        <pre><code class="language-javascript">$('body').animatescroll();</code></pre>
                        <button class="btn demo-btn" onclick="$('body').animatescroll();">Click for a Demo</button>
                        <p>
                          It gives power to the user with its various options to customize the style of scrolling, scroll speed and many more.
                          Supports more than 30 unique Scrolling Styles.
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </section>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/animatescroll.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(function() {
           $(".panel").css({"height":$(window).height()});
           $.scrollify({
             section:".panel"
           });


           $(".scroll").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $.scrollify.move("#home");
           });
         });

             //Greetings Based on the user's time

             //var offset = ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()/60)*(-1);
             //console.log(offset+'hrs');
             //console.log((new Date()).getTime());
             // var current_time = new Date().getHours()+':'+new Date().getMinutes()+':'+ new Date().getSeconds();
             var current_time = new Date().getHours();
              //console.log(current_time);
             if(current_time >=0 && current_time <12 ){
                $("#greetings").text("Good Morning!!");
             }else if(current_time >=12 && current_time <18 ){
                $("#greetings").text("Good Afternoon!!");
             }else if(current_time >=18 && current_time !=0){
                $("#greetings").hide().text("Good Evening!!").fadeIn(2000);
             }

             $(".wrapper").hide().fadeIn(2000);

             $(window).scroll(function(){
                var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
                var height = $(".home").height();
                var barposition = $(".home").offset().top;
                if(scroll >= barposition){
                    $(".fixed_nav").removeClass("hidden").hide().fadeIn(500);
                    //$(".fixed_nav").css({"position":"fixed","top":barposition});
                     console.log(barposition);
                }else{
                    console.log("not yet");
                    $(".fixed_nav").addClass("hidden");
                }
             })
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

and Css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/EsvMC5un3kjyUhB9ZEPPwg.woff2) format('woff2');
}
section,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border:0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}

.content-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-size:62.5%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
}
.panel {
    height:100vh;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}
.welcome{
    background: url("../img/background_opt.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
}
.btn-color-shihab{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    text-align: center;  
}
.btn-color-home{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    text-align: center;  
}
.btn-color-resume{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    text-align: center;  
}
.btn-color-skill{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    text-align: center;  
}
.btn-color-portfolio{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    text-align: center;  
}
.btn-color-contact{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(48,48,48,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(48,48,48,1)); 
    text-align: center;  
}
.home{
    background: url("../img/background_opt.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
}
.resume{
    background: url("../img/background_opt.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
}

.skill{
    background: url("../img/background_opt.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
}
.wrapper{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));  
}
.header_overwrite{
    display: block;
    padding-bottom:5em;
    margin:20% 0 0 28%;
}

@media(max-width:1200px){
    .header_overwrite{
        display: block;
        padding-bottom:5em;
        margin:25% 0 0 23%;
    }
}



@media(max-width:900px){
    .header_overwrite{
        display: block;
        padding-bottom:5em;
        margin:25% 0 0 14%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:700px){
    .header_overwrite{
        display: block;
        padding-bottom:5em;
        margin:40% 0 0 10%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:500px){
    .header_overwrite{
        display: block;
        padding-bottom:5em;
        margin:50% 0 0 5%;
    }
}

@media(min-width:200px){
    .h1_style {
        font-size:2em;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color:#FFF;
        padding:0em 0 0 1em;
    }
}

@media(min-width:380px){
    .h1_style {
        font-size:2.5em;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color:#FFF;
        padding:0em 0 0 1em;
    }
}
@media(min-width:550px){
    .h1_style {
        font-size:3.5em;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color:#FFF;
        padding:0em 0 0 1em;
    }
}
@media(min-width:680px){
    .h1_style {
        font-size:4em;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color:#FFF;
        padding:0em 0 0 1em;
    }
}

.h1_style {
        font-size:4em;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color:#FFF;
        padding:0em 0 0 1em;
    }

a:link,
a:visited {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}


.scroll {
    position:relative;
    font-size:1.5em;
    margin:3em 0 0 30.0em;
    display:inline-block;

}

@media(max-width:1300px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:3em 0 0 28.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}
@media(max-width:1190px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 23.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}
@media(max-width:1050px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 20.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}

@media(max-width:890px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 16.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}

@media(max-width:730px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 13.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}

@media(max-width:670px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 10.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}

@media(max-width:550px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 6.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}
@media(max-width:410px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 4.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}
@media(max-width:350px){
    .scroll {
        position:relative;
        font-size:1.5em;
        margin:2em 0 0 3.0em;
        display:inline-block;

    }
}
.scroll:after{
    content: '';
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:60px;
    border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-animation:3s arrow infinite ;
    animation:3s arrow infinite ;
}

@webkit-keyframes arrow{
    0%,100%{
        top:20px;
    }
    50%{
        top:40px;
    }   
}

@keyframes arrow{
    0%,100%{
        top:20px;
    }
    50%{
        top:40px;
    }   
}

.slide{
    background-size: cover;
}

#slide1{
    background: url("../img/bg2.jpg");
    padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}
#slide2{
    background: url("../img/bg5.jpg");
    padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}
#slide3{
    background: url("../img/bg2.jpg");
    padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}
#slide4{
    background: url("../img/bg5.jpg");
    padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: if (scroll >= *your targets offset top)
{ $("#yourMenu").css({ 'position' : 'fixed'});}
else{ $("#yourMenu").css({ 'position' : 'relative'});}

Keep in mind this is just a raw guidance, no final code, you will also need a premanent resetting of the scroll position. If nobody else does, I will make a codepen later on.